# How to set the Response Text in Spring REST exception handlers?

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpresponse

I'm working on a Spring REST controller, specifically on an exception handler. The exception handler works as intended and my JUnit-Test (using the Spring HTTP client) shows that the correct HTTP Status code (400) is received at the client. The HTTP client automatically translates this into a `HttpClientErrorException`.

However, printing the `HttpClientErrorException` always produces the following result for me:

`HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`

... and the `null` part is what worries me. **Shouldn't this be the place where the message of the server-side exception is supposed to be?**

I checked the source code of the HTTP client to see where the client-side exception is thrown. It looks like this:

`throw new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(), response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));`

Debugging this call revealed that `response.getStatusText()` is `null` in my case.

**My question is:** How do you design your `ResponseEntity` on the server-side such that the HTTP client finds the server-side exception message in `response.getStatusText()` instead of `null`?

Mine currently looks like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MyCustomException.class })
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(final HttpServletRequest req, final MyCustomException e) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-type", "text/plain");
    String body = e.toString();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

... and I get `null` in the client side status text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admit that I got fooled on this one. The `null` value printed by the Spring `HttpClientErrorException` is the `statusText`. This text is **static**. For example, for Status Code 404, the defined status text is "not found". There is no way to change it.

In order to receive the actual exception code, then the method suggested by Utku is exactly right. The small gotcha is that the error message needs to be extracted from `HttpClientErrorException#getResponseBodyAsString()`, not from `HttpClientErrorException#getStatusText()` like I tried.